# prevent some items from Refreshing data in Listview.builder

Tags: flutter

I have a Listview.builder inside a FutureBuilder which taking some data from an http request.i have a `bool closed` i want to prevent some items from  refreshing if status `bool is true`

how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing your call in `initState`. In this way you can make sure that it will get the data only once.

example:

```
class FutureSample extends StatefulWidget {
  // Create instance variable
  @override
  _FutureSampleState createState() => _FutureSampleState();
}

class _FutureSampleState extends State<FutureSample> {
  Future myFuture;

  Future<String> _fetchData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    return 'DATA';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // assign this variable your Future
    myFuture = _fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
             return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In that way you don't need a bool value. There are also different ways to achieve or extend your request. You can check this article for more informations: https://medium.com/flutterworld/why-future-builder-called-multiple-times-9efeeaf38ba2

Comment: thats mean every time i run this page in the app the function run one time ?

Comment: yes, your welcome, upvote and accept answer if it helped :)

Comment: but what i need is not refreshing some items which hit the target and closed

Comment: i have a target price in each item

Comment: I see, this is data specific, you should manage this in the function where you receive the data

Comment: so how can i do that?

Comment: show the code you got so far then i can assist you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230941/discussion-between-ali-mahdiyar-and-marcel-dz).